# Manager App, Server Status, Host Manager show 404 error

Tags: java, tomcat

[image]

This is the error log inside my server, centos 7.
I have install the tomcat 9 inside this server, and start all tomcat service.
Already set the user role inside, port open, just not sure what this error log mean.
What is the meaning of this error log?
And which part i have missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either something is wrong within your /WEB-INF/jsp/403.jsp.
Or it doesn't exist when it's expecting it to.

The exception specifically mentions servlet mappings, so it may also be worth while checking your web.xml/servlet annotations.